# Scala unit test to check for constant value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the below columns in a Dataframe and all of them contain integer values 0 or 1

```
df
 - col1
 - col2
 - col3
```

How can I write a Scala unit test to check if the column values are only 0 and 1?

I am trying to do below but it doesnt work. Can someone suggest a simple way.

```
    val testDF = Seq(0, 1).toDF("expected_values")

    assert df.select("col1").distinct() == testDF
    assert df.select("col2").distinct() == testDF
    assert df.select("col3").distinct() == testDF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just count the values which are not 0 or 1, and compare to 0.

```
assert df.filter("col1 not in (0,1)").count() == 0
```